# How to block administrators access to other pages in ASP .NET MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, authorize.net

In my ASP .NET MVC 3 application I use 2 separate user tables(one for users and one for admins).

Do there are independent and admin have not any privileges to access pages for users(he must only have access to his Area). How can I do that?

For administrators I use custom Authorize, so users can't have access to Admin Area.

```
public class AdminAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            UnitOfWork Unit = new UnitOfWork();
            string username = filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
            if (!Unit.AdminSrvc.AdminAuthorize(username))
            {
                filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
            }
        }
    }
```

But Admin still can see other pages, because he is authenticated. How can I solve that problem?

Answer (score 3):

What about adding "User" role that admins wouldn't have ?

```
[Authorize(Roles = "User")]
```

Comment: I don't use the asp_membership. I created custom user and admin table.

Comment: Introduce roles! This is the concept to separate access.

Comment: You dont need asp_membership to use roles. We use custom auth system and roles. Works well.